# getting textarea data from innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Is it possible to get  data while collecting a whole set of innerHTML data?

Here is a part of my JS code.

```
var css = document.getElementById('SETinfo').innerHTML;
var num = parseInt(document.getElementById('stepNum_count').value);
var name = document.getElementById('step_name_'+id).value;
var desc = document.getElementById('step_desc_'+id).value;
  css += "<div id='new_step_num_"+num+"'>";
  css += "<input type='hidden' name='new_VW_step[]' value='"+id+"'>";
  css += "<div class='step_contain'><div class='step'>";
  css += "<div class='step_circle'>";
  if(num < 10)
    {
  css += "<div class='step_num'>"+num+"</div>";
    }
  else
    {
  css += "<div class='step_num' style='left:8px;'>"+num+"</div>";
    }
  css += "</div>";
  css += "<div class='step_name'>"+name+"</div>";
  css += "<div class='step_divider'> </div>";
  css += "<textarea class='step_detail' name='step_desc_[]'>"+desc+"</textarea>";
  css += "</div> </div>";
  css += "</div>";

document.getElementById('SETinfo').innerHTML = css;
num = num + 1;
```

Everything works properly minus the textarea, which doesn't get collected/selected.

Here is a JSfiddle of a simplified verison of what i'm trying to do. Note that when you enter text into the textarea it does not get carried over when you click the button.
http://jsfiddle.net/MepG5/

Comment: From which elements are you collecting the data? Is there some missing HTML?

Comment: Not really relevant to your question, but I am curious, why are you sticking a bunch of HTML in a variable called 'css'?

Comment: @showdev I have a div in my HTML called SETinfo where I have a several elements.

Comment: @NicoleBieber the var css is just an arbitrary var name. it can be SomeHTML for all i care. I'm carrying the innerHTML because I update that SETinfo div with other elements.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working, because you're trying to add **tags** to **innerHTML.**  `var css = document.getElementById('SETinfo').innerHTML;` works fine.  Use [entities:](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

```
var css = document.getElementById('SETinfo').innerHTML;
var num = parseInt(document.getElementById('stepNum_count').value);
var name = document.getElementById('step_name_'+id).value;
var desc = document.getElementById('step_desc_'+id).value;
  css += "&lt;div id='new_step_num_"+num+"'&gt;";
  css += "&lt;input type='hidden' name='new_VW_step[]' value='"+id+"'&gt;";
  css += "&lt;div class='step_contain'&gt;&lt;div class='step'&gt;";
  css += "&lt;div class='step_circle'&gt;";
  if(num < 10)
    {
  css += "&lt;div class='step_num'&gt;"+num+"&lt;/div&gt;";
    }
  else
    {
  css += "&lt;div class='step_num' style='left:8px;'&gt;"+num+"&lt;/div&gt;";
    }
  css += "&lt;/div&gt;";
  css += "&lt;div class='step_name'&gt;"+name+"&lt;/div&gt;";
  css += "&lt;div class='step_divider'&gt; &lt;/div&gt;";
  css += "&lt;textarea class='step_detail' name='step_desc_[]'&gt;"+desc+"&lt;/textarea&gt;";
  css += "&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt;";
  css += "&lt;/div&gt;";

document.getElementById('SETinfo').innerHTML = css;
num = num + 1;
```

Comment: Hi Man of Snow, When go with this method all the elements become text.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   var textarea = $('textarea').val();
```

and then instead of

```
css += "<textarea class='step_detail' name='step_desc_[]'>"+desc+"</textarea>";
```

write

```
css += textarea;
```

Comment: He doesn't want to use **JQuery,** and what he *has* is fine.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out how to resolve this one way. When each text area is created I assign a unique ID using a number counter, then I count the number of rows created so far, collect the values, add the html then repopulate the data in each text area based on number counter. I can  update the JSfiddle if anyone cares to see the actual code.